# Stripe Connect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

trying to get back the necessary information after a Stripe user connects with my application, just started out and have this so far, putting the data in specific variables like so:

```
provider =  request.env["omniauth.auth"].provider,
uid =  request.env["omniauth.auth"].uid,
access_code = request.env["omniauth.auth"].credentials.token,
publishable_key = request.env["omniauth.auth"].info.stripe_publishable_key
```

when i "skip the form" i get redirected to the session#index and i get this error `undefined method provider for nil:NilClass`

here is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'login#index'  

  get 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'
  post 'login/log_in' => 'login#log_in'


  get 'login/logout' 

  get 'sessions/index'

  get '/auth/stripe_connect/callback', to: 'sessions#index'

end
```

Comment: You're seeing that error because `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` is not defined. Can you clarify what you mean by "skip the form"?

Comment: when skipping the form, redirection to my url with those params sent over so i can save.

Comment: is there something i forgot to do so maybe thats why its not defined?